# file_get_contents() returns "failed to open stream" when hitting HTTPS

Tags: php, facebook, iis-7

file_get_contents() is returning "failed to open stream" when I call it on an HTTPS URL.

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://google.com) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No error in E:\\htdocs\callback3.php on line 5
```

Same call **will** work with a non-SSL URL.

At first, I thought it was a security issue with my webhoster, but I have verified with phpinfo() that **allow url open** is indeed allowed.  I have also tried this code and verified it works:

Anyone have any ideas why file_get_contents() is failing with an HTTPS URL?

**update:** People correctly pointed out this was an HTTPS issue. My webhoster claims this should work, and has no idea how to resolve this.  Anyone have specific directions I can give them for their IIS7 setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is probably because they are using the secure protocol `https`. This is strange though, in their examples, facebook is giving the similar example.

Comment: +1, PHP needs to have SSL compiled in for SSL to work. Although, on my dev-server the lack of SSL gave an error of `failed to open stream: Invalid argument ` with `file_get_contents`. But double check your PHPinfo output for SSL support.

Comment: From the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php): "Note: HTTPS is supported starting from PHP 4.3.0, if you have compiled in support for OpenSSL"

Comment: @nikc: yup, that is the case and useful info added. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I wish the error message was more informative!  I looked at phpinfo() but didn't know where to look for SSL support info.  However, given https wasn't listed in "Registered PHP streams" I'm assuming it's not support.  I have an email out to the webhoster to see if this can be changed.

Comment: My webhoster is on a windows stack, so running IIS 7.  They have no idea how to troubleshooter this SSL support and claim it should work contrary to it failing.  Anyone have specific directions I can give them?

Comment: I think they should turn on the openssl extensin in php ini.