# Problems to open remote secure file with file_get_contents(php)

Tags: php, facebook, helper

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [file_get_contents() returns “failed to open stream” when hitting HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809068/file-get-contents-returns-failed-to-open-stream-when-hitting-https)

how can i open https://~ urls with file_get_contents? it's possible to do?

i'm getting 'failed to open stream: No error in~

Comment: is the openssl extension enabled?

Comment: SecFilterEngine i believe referrers to mod_security. you need to check your php install and make sure you have the openssl extension enabled in the php.ini

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's easier to just use CURL, since you can do some more stuff with it

Really basic:

```
 $ch = curl_init("https://url.to/secured.file");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 $file = curl_exec($ch);
```