# How can I get facebook cover url from Facebook graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use: `http://graph.facebook.com/{user_id or page_id}?fields=cover`

Return on browser:

```
{
  "cover": {
    "id": "XXX", 
    "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/311205_989690200741_1231438675_n.jpg", 
    "offset_y": 66
  }, 
  "id": "XXXXXX"
}
```

How can I get field `source` and `offset_y` to `PHP` variables?

My function:

```
function cover_img($fb_user_name) {
    $cover_data = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$fb_user_name.'?fields=cover';
    $JSONString = file_get_contents($cover_data);
    $parsedJSON = json_decode($JSONString);
    echo $source = $parsedJSON->cover->source;
    echo $offset_y = $parsedJSON->cover->offset_y;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To parse the JSON in PHP you are required to use [`json_decode(returned_facebook_json)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and then access the data as you access a Object, for example

```
$JSONString=file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/{user_id or page_id}?fields=cover');
$parsedJSON = json_decode($JSONString);
echo $source = $parsedJSON->cover->source;
echo $offset_y = $parsedJSON->cover->offset_y;
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know to get **returned_facebook_json_string** in
`json_decode(returned_facebook_json_string);`

Please tell me how to?

Comment: Yes! i'm using `http://graph.facebook.com/{user_id or page_id}?fields=cover` from a answer on stackoverflow, but I don't know to get PHP variables from it :(

How to get `returned_facebook_json_string` to use JSON decode like your answer?

Comment: I have updated my answer with complete code, try it and tell if that solves your problem

Comment: Thank you @Anvesh Saxena, but it have a problem: `Warning: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/pepsi?fields=cover) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No error in E:\AppServ\www\demo\wp-content\themes\HayNhat\functions\get_facebook_data.php on line 15`
. I have update the function on my question.

Comment: You code is working correctly for me, but you may check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809068/file-get-contents-returns-failed-to-open-stream-when-hitting-https) for similar issue. Also check if your `allow_url_fopen is false/off` by Checking phpinfo() or php.ini or ini_get('allow_url_fopen').

Comment: Thank you @Anvesh Saxena, I will try again.